# Possible to install Xmonad on Ubuntu separate from Gnome?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, window-manager, gdm, xmonad

I just downloaded Xmonad from the repository on my Ubuntu 10.04 box, but when I log out and try to log back in using Xmonad instead Gnome, it doesn't work.

I just get the login screen background image and a mousepointer, and nothing else.  Right-clicking does nothing, no menus or anything.  Key combo's like Ctrl-X, Ctrl-Z, and Ctrl-Alt-Delete do nothing either.  Left the computer in this state for 30 minutes while I went to the grocery store, but it was still hung when I returned and I had to hard-reboot it.

A Google search returned a few sites showing how to configure Xmonad to work *with* Gnome, but I'm afraid to try this since I don't want to risk borking my Gnome installation, at least not until I've had a chance to learn Xmonad a bit.

Is it possible to run Xmonad independently of Gnome?  If so, anyone have any idea what might be wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: sounds like you just need to configure xmonad.  i don't use it so i can't give you specifics, but check the docs at http://xmonad.org/ ... you might find some sample configurations to help you get started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hit Mod+Shift+Return to launch a terminal.  Mod is likely left-alt or left-Win

Answer (score 1):

Xmonad is a tiling window manager, and from what I understand it's very, very minimal, which means it does not include a menu.  Have a look at [the guided tour](http://xmonad.org/tour.html) on the Xmonad website, which should get you going.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're running Xmonad just fine. As maco said, hit Mod+Shift+Return to open a terminal window.

Also, if you have dmenu installed, you can hit Mod+P to bring up a search box for all installed applications (appears at the top of the screen, typically).

Answer (score 0):

[xmonad](http://xmonad.org/) is a tiling window manager as mentioned above. As such, it is mostly geared towards a mouseless desktop experience.

You can customize xmonad with external programs like [dmenu](http://tools.suckless.org/dmenu/), [xmobar](http://gorgias.mine.nu/xmobar/)/dgen to give you minimal menu selection via keyboard and a status bar/notification bar.

Comment: This is nor really an answer, you should post this kind of information as a comment.